# Change the splash screen on moto e4 plus owens

Tags: lineageos

I was rooting my device and I screwed it up but I got twrp to runs and I installed Lineage OS. But after I restarted my device, there is a tiny `n/a` in the corner until the Lineage's logo appears. I searched for a while but came up dry. It's not that bad but I would like something else to be shown instead of `n/a`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So I downloaded the zip file and in the menu selected moto e1/2 and I added an image and I transferred the zip to the phone and then tried to flash it and it spit up error code 6

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it, but both methods will require some files.

#### Method 1: fastboot

1. Aquire a splashscreen file in the format of '.bin'. You can either search for 
   splashscreen .bin files made for your device, or find a tool that allows you to convert and image to a splashscreen .bin.
2. Put your phone in bootloader mode manually or with adb:

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

3. Flash the new logo to the device:

```
fastboot flash logo filename.bin
```

#### Method 2: TWRP

1. Install TWRP as your bootloader (in your case you already have)
2. Aquire a zip file specifically crafted for your device to flash a splashscreen logo*
3. Copy the zip to your phone via OTG or SD-card and flash it with TWRP

*Note: as far as I've seen the zip file only needs to contain three files:

- META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary
- META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script
- logo.bin **OR** splash.bin **OR** logo.img

But they have to be specifically crafted for your device, and in order to do that you will need a tool. See [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/guide-how-to-create-custom-boot-logo-t3470473) to find a guide with tools for your device.

Edit: I checked the thread for your phones product line, it looks like the E4 Plus is unsupported, [at least nobody has added support for it here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/themes-apps/app-motorola-boot-logo-maker-source-t2848667/post76592266#post76592266). You might need to look elsewhere for a tool that can make images for your phone.